# ssh disconnect: broken pipe

Tags: ssh, connection

When I'm connected to an ssh server, I often get disconnected with the error

```
packet_write_wait: Connection to 131.225.190.20: Broken pipe
```

I'm connected via cable. I don't see any instabilities in my connection on other servers. I have `ServerAliveInterval` set in my `ssh config`.

What could cause this disrupts? What can I do against it? I know about `tmux`.